# Resequencer for MediatR INotificationHandler - can't use IPipelineBehavior

Tags: c#, simple-injector, mediatr

I have seen MediatR `IPipelineBehavior<TRequest, TResponse>` and looking to use a resequencer for event bus notifications to be put in order. The aspect orientated angle is very interesting/useful to split up functionality into separate handlers.

I can see the docs mention:

> pipeline behaviors are only compatible with
>   `IRequestHandler<TRequest,TResponse>` and can't be used with
>   `INotificationHandler<TRequest>`.

What would be the way around this is there an equivalent behaviors/transformation pipeline for `INotification` and `INotificationHandler`?

Or would one use a DI container such as my favorite `SimpleInjector` and register decorators to wrap specific event handlers where i want re-sequencing to take place by wrapping specific notification handlers?

```
class ResequencerEventHandler<T> : INotificationHandler<T> where T : INotification, ISequencedMessage
{
   readonly IResequencer _resequencer;
   readonly INotificationHandler<T> _handler;

   public ResequencerEventHandler(INotificationHandler<T> handler, IResequencer resequencer)
   {
      _resequencer = resequencer;
      _handler = handler;
   }

   public Task Handle(T notification)
   {
      _resequencer.Add(notification);

      while(_resequencer.CanDequeue)
      {
          var packet = _resequencer.Dequeue();
          _handler(packet);
      }

      return Task.CompletedTask;
   }
}
```

Just trying to work out the best place to do this, as seem to be able to do this (with IRequests at least) both in `MediatR` and `SimpleInjector`.

Comment: Ok thanks Steven, if you want to pop that in as an answer that's exactly what i was looking for and will mark accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I would certainly ditch those pipeline behaviors and replace them with decorators. Decorators make a much simpler model to implement cross-cutting concerns. Older versions of MediatR actually used decorators instead of these pipeline behavior. AFAIK, the only reason newer MediatR versions don't use decorators is because it tries to make a model that works on all containers, even on those that have poor support for decorators (such as MS.DI, Unity, etc.).

Comment: Thanks Steven also by using decorators i can wrap INotification which is what i need to do in this case.